# Flag run-length of grouped intervals

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe grouped by `grp`:

```
df <- data.frame(
  v = rnorm(25),
  grp = c(rep("A",10), rep("B",15)),
  size = 2)
```

I want to flag the run-length of intervals determined by `size`. For example, for `grp == "A"`, `size` is `2`, and the number of rows is `10`. So the interval should have length 10/2 = 5. This code, however, creates intervals with length `2`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  mutate(
    interval = (row_number() -1) %/% size)
# A tibble: 25 × 4
# Groups:   grp [2]
        v grp    size interval
    <dbl> <chr> <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 -0.166 A         2        0
 2 -1.12  A         2        0
 3  0.941 A         2        1
 4 -0.913 A         2        1
 5  0.486 A         2        2
 6 -1.80  A         2        2
 7 -0.370 A         2        3
 8 -0.209 A         2        3
 9 -0.661 A         2        4
10 -0.177 A         2        4
# … with 15 more rows
```

How can I flag the correct run-length of the `size`-determined intervals? The desired output is this:

```
# A tibble: 25 × 4
# Groups:   grp [2]
        v grp    size interval
    <dbl> <chr> <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 -0.166 A         2        0
 2 -1.12  A         2        0
 3  0.941 A         2        0
 4 -0.913 A         2        0
 5  0.486 A         2        0
 6 -1.80  A         2        1
 7 -0.370 A         2        1
 8 -0.209 A         2        1
 9 -0.661 A         2        1
10 -0.177 A         2        1
# … with 15 more rows
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I interpreted your question correctly, this small change should do the trick?

```
df %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  mutate(
    interval = (row_number() -1) %/% (n()/size))
```

Comment: Looks good. I had tried `(row_number() -1) %/% n()/size)` (without the parentheses you inserted) but it didn't work. What do the added parentheses do?

Comment: `%/%` is performed before the division. So `6%/%10/2` equals `(6%/%10)/2` which is `0/2 = 0`, whereas `6%/%(10/2)` equals `6%/%5` which is 1

Comment: `%/%` indicates integer division. It divides two numbers and returns the integer part of the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gl`:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  mutate(interval = gl(first(size), ceiling(n() / first(size)))[1:n()])
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 26 × 4
# Groups:   grp [2]
         v grp    size interval
     <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <fct>   
 1 -1.12   A         2 1       
 2  3.04   A         2 1       
 3  0.235  A         2 1       
 4 -0.0333 A         2 1       
 5 -2.73   A         2 1       
 6 -0.0998 A         2 1       
 7  0.976  A         2 2       
 8  0.414  A         2 2       
 9  0.912  A         2 2       
10  1.98   A         2 2       
11  1.17   A         2 2       
12 -0.509  B         2 1       
13  0.704  B         2 1       
14 -0.198  B         2 1       
15 -0.538  B         2 1       
16 -2.86   B         2 1       
17 -0.790  B         2 1       
18  0.488  B         2 1       
19  2.17   B         2 1       
20  0.501  B         2 2       
21  0.620  B         2 2       
22 -0.966  B         2 2       
23  0.163  B         2 2       
24 -2.08   B         2 2       
25  0.485  B         2 2       
26  0.697  B         2 2
```

Comment: `size` is, obviously, not always `2`

Comment: Yes, `size` is the same withing the groups. But the count should be continuous. That is, when there are more than 2 intervals, these intervals should be counted incrementally 3, 4, etc. See, for example the `interval` value in row #25: with your code it is 1, whereas it should be 3!

Comment: yes, `size` is always constant across `grp`but obviously, in the actual data, has many distinct values